# Updating node 6.2 to node > 8 in openshift 3

Tags: node.js, openshift, rhel, openshift-3

I created a node 6.2 and MongoDB project on openshift 3. I don't have the root access to the terminal. I can redeploy if needed. How can I update node? I want to use the async/await functionality.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you create project? Did you use s2i?